# Org json parsing keep getting error - is not a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Im trying to parse id from following string json:

```
postResponse :{"success":true,"response_json":"{\"status\":200,\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":{\"id\":\"f71233gg12\"}}"}
```

my code looks like below:

```
System.out.println("postResponse :"+postResponse);
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(postResponse);
JSONObject jsonObjectA = responseJson.getJSONObject("response_json");
JSONObject jsonObjectB = jsonObjectA.getJSONObject("data");
String the_pdf_id = jsonObjectB.get("id").toString();
```

i keep getting the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["response_json"] is not a JSONObject.
```

what could be the reason? any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on your data, the content at key `response_json` is not a an object, but only a string, another JSON-encoded string

```
// response_json value is a string
{"success":true,"response_json":"{\"status\":200,\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":{\"id\":\"f71233gg12\"}}"}

// response_json value is an object
{"success":true,"response_json": {"status":200,"message":"Success","data":{"id":"f71233gg12"}}}
```

You need a second parse level

```
JSONObject jsonObjectA = new JSONObject(responseJson.getJSONString("response_json"));
```